# Proving Equivalance relation (transitivity)

Tags: proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

$$relation = {(a, b) | b − 3 < a ∧ a < b + 3}$$

Unsure how to proof transitivity. Also is my reflexive and symetric proof strong enough?

A = $\{\mathbb{Z}\}$
Reflexive: yes because $\forall x \in A, (x,x) \in relation.$
Symetric: yes because $\forall x,y \in A, (x,y) \in relation \xrightarrow[]{} (y,x) \in relation$.
Transitive: ?

I know the definition but unsure how to approach the last proof

Comment: Experiment with $b = 1, a = 3, c = 5$.  $b$ is within $2$ of $a$ and $a$ is within $2$ of $c$.

Comment: Agree about reflexivity and symmetry, but transitivity is suspect:  0,2,4, where (0,2) and (2,4) are "in the relation", but (0,4) are not.

Comment: @blamocur Thanks this work. But how on earth did you come to this conclusion. I was doing trial and error for a good hour.

Comment: @Olivia22  I drew point $a$, then the set/interval of all $b$'s which are "in the relation" with $a$; fixed a $b$ near the edges of the set, then drew the set/interval of all $c$'s which are in the relation with $b$. From such diagram one can see that some $c$'s are too far (farther than 3) from $a$.